# numericUpDown prevent rounding int

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, rounding, numericupdown

I'm using numericUpDown with C# to represent integers. But there is a problem representing "big values". For instance if I assgin 127 to numericUpDown, it's displayed correctly. However, if I assign 12912347 it gets rounded to 12912350.

How can I avoid numericUpDown rounding integers?

(numericUpDown settings are: DecimalPlaces 0; Maximum 4294967295; Minimum 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the are `decimal` values and it easily [covers your range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). Also i'm not able to reproduce this.

So it seems, that there is a problem somewhere else in your code that performs such a rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce that (Fx 4).

Value, Minimum and Maximum are all `decimal` properties so there should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my mistake indeed. I used an invoke and there sth like this was done:
float value = 12912347f;
numericUpDown1.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
this conversion caused the rounding.

This question should probably be deleted.